# Using Cisco Wave 474 as normal PC

Tags: desktop, compatibility, legacy

My employer recently upgraded the server room and threw a lot of hardware away. I noticed the Cisco Wave 474 devices which look just like standard PC's. They've got a nice amount of RAM and a Core Duo inside which could still make them a nice Internet-Surf-PC for home.

Since my employer did only remove the harddisk I took one home and wonder if I could convert it to a standard PC.

Before I buy a new harddisk: Does anyone know those devices? Can I have success with my plan or are Ciscos modifications too big to get them working?